# Whenver i try to run ./startFAbric.sh i get an error "Error respomse from daemon"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been trying to run this:

```
 ./startFabric.sh commandline
```

and it is showing the following error:

Sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up.

```
Error response from daemon: Container e7e73f14680e75372fe535dd6af95a88af2e6a704afd0ad69671ea0ec4a00922 is not running.....
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ./startFabric.sh *

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when running ./startFabric.sh command. But I have resolved it by using

`docker start 84bff00c3ed981e5a59061bb78411308d047f8a9996d838bc54df26e786a7963`

this command. And then try using again `./startFabric.sh` command.

I hope this will solve your problem.

For more detail, please check the given link.
https://github.com/IBM/Decentralized-Energy-Composer/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your docker containers running for longer than 15 Secs.

This command helped me;

```
ls -la /; sleep 10m
```

You can run this and retry the `./startFabric.sh` command on another terminal.